# Problem with external links remapped

Tags: url, apache

I have a site based on Joomla. It worked perfectly but I had to move it from one server to another. Since that there's a problem with external URLs - they are rewritten in such way: foreignsite.com => mysite.com/"foreignsite.com" Needless to say that it causes 404 error. I've tried: renaming .htaccess and changing joomla SEO options. Both with no luck and no effect at all. I have completely no idea what to try to do next.
The server is running on apache, PHP 5.3, Joomla 3.1.1.
I kindly ask for your help.

Comment: Do you have re-write base set in .htaccess?

Comment: Try using a fresh new htaccess file.

Comment: So you are saying that disabling URL rewrite is still giving you this issue ?

Comment: No matter what I have in .htaccess, the server seems not to see any changes, though it used to some time ago.
Creating a fresh .htaccess file did not change anything. Nor disabling rewrite engine.
Thank you for trying to help me! I still count on your advice.

Comment: I found whenever this happens it's because I didn't put http:// in front of the url, especially in JCE. It assumes it's an internal link and puts my site url in front of it. I suspect that's not your issue, but I thought I'd share that in case it is.

Comment: Thank you very much, Brian, you helped me to figure out that the problem is caused by the joomla article editor that adds rubbish to the code (" changes to "\&quot;) before sending it to database. When I login to phpMyAdmin and clear the article out of junk, the links work as they should. But my next question is: what to do to fix the editor so that I could edit my files in the back-end? Changing TinyMce to Simple does not work.

Comment: It might not be your editor that's the problem. You might want to check with your web host or see if your database is using the wrong format. It sounds like it's trying to do something to your code that it shouldn't be doing.

Answer (score 1):

use `http://foreignsite.com` instead of `foreignsite.com`

Comment: I've already tried that, the result is: mysite.com/"http:foreignsite.com"

Answer (score 0):

In your *configuration.php* on line 20, you should see a variable called `$live_site`.

Try changing it so that is reads:

```
public $live_site = 'http://mysite.com';
```

Comment: No success but thanks for reply.

Comment: `public $live_site = 'http://mysite.com';` 

live site is always The actual URL of the site for example - `http://yourdomain.com` (unless your site is in a subdirectory) never an external url to the site.

(the answer has been edited, pending peer review)